# Cassandra data import with logged BATCH statements in the same row (different clustering key) not recognized by subsequent SELECT using WHERE

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-enterprise

I am seeing a very strange effect, which I cannot explain myself with my current knowledge of Cassandra. I would like to know if this behavior is to be expected or could be a potential bug.

My setup is as follows:

Nodes:

```
Two DSE 4.0.2 nodes, running Cassandra 2.0.6.
```

Keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {
    'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'Cassandra': 1
};
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    lid uuid,
    lkey text, 
    line int, 
    original text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (lid, lkey, line)
);
```

Data Import Program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = ... // not important

        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();

        UUID lid = UUIDs.timeBased();
        int testsize = 99941;

        for (int i = 1; i <= testsize; i++) {
            batch.add(QueryBuilder.insertInto("test")
                    .value("lid", lid)
                    .value("lkey", Hashing.md5().hashLong(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
                    .value("line", i)
                    .value("original", "test data xy")
            );

            if (batch.getStatements().size() >= 1000 || i == testsize) {
                System.out.println("Sending a batch of " + batch.getStatements().size() + " statements, " + i + " total.");
                session.execute(batch);
                batch = new BatchStatement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I query this data from a CQL Shell, for example with the statement:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test LIMIT 100000;
```

I get the expected answer:

```
99941
```

If, however, I ask for the partitioning key:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lid FROM test;
```

and use it to narrow down the query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE lid=<the-correct-uuid> LIMIT 100000;
```

the answer suddenly is just

```
54588
```

The implicit write and read consistency levels are ONE and I only have one replica. Note that there is no other data in the table and all rows have the same partitioning key. Tracing the queries reveals that the query without WHERE does a full SSTable scan, whereas the query with the WHERE gets pointed towards some SSTables by the key cache.

The effect vanished after compacting the SSTables and I get the same 99941 in both queries.

Running the test again, I get another 99941 entries, with a fresh partitioning key, this time the number returned is

```
46674
```

and querying the first partitioning key still yields the same result. In our real system, we sometimes even get the correct answer we expect.

Any hints to why this is ok, why this might be a bug or why this might have to do with our setup are appreciated.

Thank you!

**edit:**

I noticed that switching to unlogged batch statements also circumvents the problem, which does not seem too surprising to me at least...

**edit:**

The test also yields the correct result in many cases... truncating the table helps in raising the odds of showing the effect, it seems.

**edit:**

Can't reproduce in 4.0.3. The query takes significantly longer to process, but seems to be correct now. Longer means closer to the full scan.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still replicate this in DSE 4.0.3 I would file a bug.  I think something was fixed with select count and memtables at some point.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I assume it is a bug then. The kind of query should not matter and the result should be consistent. I cannot reproduce it in 4.0.3, at least not in several tries.